# Smoke alarm ion neutralisation

Tags: everyday-chemistry, ions, safety, ionic-compounds

Smoke alarms are a necessary part of many modern day buildings, especially in laboratories and of course, the family home.

According to the World Nuclear Association page [Smoke Detectors and Americium](http://www.world-nuclear.org/info/non-power-nuclear-applications/radioisotopes/smoke-detectors-and-americium/) (2014), a major part of the operation of a smoke detector is when the Americium-241 emits alpha particles collide with atmospheric oxygen and nitrogen, ionising them - which form part of an electric current between two electrodes.

When there is smoke (from the article) - bolding mine:

> When smoke enters the space between the electrodes, **the smoke particles attach to the charged ions, neutralizing them**. This causes the number of ions present – and therefore the electric current – to fall, which sets off an alarm.

**What is the chemical process that causes smoke to neutralise the charged oxygen and nitrogen ions in smoke alarms?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CFAQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ismtii2011.org%2Farticle%2Fxml%2Fsub%2Ffile_download.kin%3Fmain_no%3D202%26mode%3Dpdf&ei=4mBDVZGhNY63uQS8toHYCQ&usg=AFQjCNH4KEifjFcA8P6pE9KxmsMyLXjbyA&sig2=hgnbBozls-uaDFqTWlOHew&bvm=bv.92189499,d.c2E&cad=rja) paper, found the mechanism for neutralisation,

> **Smoke particle charge interaction**
>
> When smoke particles enter in the ionization chamber, they are
>   subjected to the electric field generated by electrodes but also to the
>   one generated by the charges. Close to the charges, the electric field is
>   highly divergent resulting in [dielectrophoretic force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectrophoresis) acting on smoke
>   particles. The force tends to bind the smoke particles to the charges.
>   When smoke particles are considered as isotropic neutral dielectric
>   bodies linearly and homogeneously polarisable, dielectrophoretic
>   force F can be expressed as
>
> $ F = \frac{1}{2} \alpha v \overrightarrow{grad} |E^{2} |$
>
> where $\alpha$ depends on smoke particle polarizability, $v$ is the smoke
>   particle volume and $E$ is the electric field produced by the charges
>   [11]. Coefficient $\alpha$ is typically of the order of $\epsilon_{0}/3$ [12] where $\epsilon_{0}$ is the
>   dielectric constant of air. Volume $v$ is approximately $4 \mu m^{3} $ for a 1-$\mu m $
>   diameter smoke particle.
>   Amplitude of electric field $E$ produced by charges is given by
>   coulomb’s law:
>
> $ E = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{q}{r^{2}}$
>
> in which $r$ is the distance between the charge and the smoke particle.
>   Due to the divergence of the field, the dielectrophoretic force
>   decrease as $\frac{1}{r^{5}}$. If a smoke particle is close to a charge then they can bind. If the smoke particle is relatively far from the charge, the time
>   of interaction may be relatively long and it is necessary that the
>   charge drifts sufficiently slowly in the chamber to optimize the
>   interaction. Indeed if the charge passes too rapidly there will be not
>   enough time for the smoke particle to bind and thus nothing would be
>   detected. In fact the capture radius reduces with the electric field and
>   is of the order of 10 $\mu m $ for $E= 1  V/mm$.
>
> When the smoke particles attach to the free charges due to
>   electrophoresis force, the charges become heavy bodies then the
>   charge mobility $\mu$ decreases resulting in a drop of the electric current
>   measured between the electrodes of the ionization chamber.
>   Even if ionic detectors are very efficient, according to new
>   standards they are no longer authorised in almost all of the developed
>   countries because of the radioactive sources they include for
>   generating the ions. Such radioactive sources are indeed difficult to
>   collect and to recycle.